# MD5 Hash of files in a Windows folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, md5

I'm trying to create md5 hash values for all files in a folder. So I created a Windows batch file for this. Below is the script I'm using

```
for /r %%f in (*) do (
certutil -hashfile %%f MD5
)
>> output.txt
```

This comes up with an error of 'Too many arguments, expected 2 received 4'. I understand that if I use `md5.exe %%f`it would work, but I don't seem to have md5.exe installed by default. And I can't install that utility due to environment restrictions.

Can someone please help?

Many Thanks

Comment: Try to quote the file name: `certutil -hashfile "%%f" MD5`

Comment: @MCND This works perfectly, thanks a ton!

Comment: If you are looking for a really good functional batch file check out this. http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7592

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script works fine in directories which don't have spaces in their path, but fails with unexpected number of arguments for directories with spaces. So fix should be simple: replace `%%f` with `"%%f"`